# Table has several columns with the same type of information

Tags: pandas-groupby

My table has 4 columns: order_id, item_id_1, item_id_2 and item_id_3. The three last columns cover the same type of information (the ids of products). I want to transform this table to get 2-columns table with "order_id" and "item_id", so my columns cover unique type of informations. That means, if in a particular order_id there were 3 products ordered, I will get three (instead of one) rows in my new table).
This will alow me, for exapmle, perform 'grupby' operation on 'item_id" column to count how meny times a particular product was ordered.
How this table transformation process is called?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have a dataframe like this -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'order_id':[1,2,3], 'item_id_1':['a','b','c'], 'item_id_2':['x','y',''], 'item_id_3':['','q','']})
df 
     order_id item_id_1 item_id_2 item_id_3
0         1         a         x
1         2         b         y         q
2         3         c

pd.melt(df, id_vars=['order_id'], \
        value_vars=['item_id_1', 'item_id_2', 'item_id_3'], \
        var_name='item_id', value_name='item_value').\
        replace('',np.nan).dropna().\
        sort_values(['order_id']).\
        reset_index(drop=True)\
        [['order_id', 'item_id']]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not aware of any method that allows you to expand rows automatically as you're suggesting, but you can easily reach you're goal without. Let's start from a similar data frame, I put nan in cells of items that have not been ordered:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'order_id':[1,2,3],'item_id_1':[11,12,13],'item_id_2':[21,np.nan,23],'item_id_3':[31,np.nan,np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cols = ['item_id_1','item_id_2','item_id_3']

print(df)

Out:
   order_id  item_id_1  item_id_2  item_id_3
0         1         11       21.0       31.0
1         2         12        NaN        NaN
2         3         13       23.0        NaN
```

Then you can define a new empty data frame to fill by iterating through the rows of the initial one. For every item a new row is added to the empty data frame with same order_id and different item_id.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['order_id','item_id']) # ,'item_num']


for ind, row in df.iterrows():
  new_row = {}
  new_row['order_id'] = row['order_id']
  for col in cols:   # for num, col in enumerate(cols):
    item = row[col]
    if not pd.isna(item):
      new_row['item_id'] = item
      # new_row['item_num'] = num +1

      new_df = new_df.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)

print(new_df)

Out: # shape (6,2), ok because because 6 items have been ordered 
       order_id  item_id
0       1.0     11.0
1       1.0     21.0
2       1.0     31.0
3       2.0     12.0
4       3.0     13.0
5       3.0     23.0
```

If you want, you could also add a third column to keep trace of the category of each item (i.e. if it was item_1, 2 or 3) by uncommenting the lines in the code, which gives you this output:

```
   order_id  item_id  item_num
0       1.0     11.0       1.0
1       1.0     21.0       2.0
2       1.0     31.0       3.0
3       2.0     12.0       1.0
4       3.0     13.0       1.0
5       3.0     23.0       2.0
```